Flow - Display selected date value immediately in a text field
I am trying to format the Date field (real-time) in a flow: MM-DD-YYYY upon selecting a date value within the screen flow.
Meaning, once the user selects a date in the field: Status Date, I want to format the date to MM-DD-YYYY and display it in another text field: Status Date Value.
I've used this formula in the 'Default Value' option of the text field: Status Date Value -
TEXT(MONTH({!inputStatus_Date}))+ "-" + TEXT(DAY({!inputStatus_Date}))+ "-" + TEXT(YEAR({!inputStatus_Date}))

All I am getting in the text field: --
How to get the date value dynamically formatted on the screen flow?

Thanks @identigral, that was the same I referred too, but that doesn't get me dynamic display.

what version is your flow running as? Reactive screen flow components are relatively new

@cropredy That could be the reason. Our dev org is running V52. And in the Automation Settings, I see: Enable Reactive Components for Screen Flows running API Version 57 and 58. If you upgrade your flows to API version 59, you don’t need this.
I will see if that setting would fix our issue, but I have to wait until a day or two as I need to get approval for that org-level change.

@cropredy Yes, you were right. Upon updating the flow version to V61, I can see the date value displaying dynamically (i.e., reactive) on to the text field. Thanks, I appreciate your help here.

Reactive screen components were recently added to SFDC Screen Flows (Winter 24 V59.0 Release Notes). I suggest you check your API version used by your screen flow and if before V59.0, update to the latest SFDC PROD version (V61 at the time of this writing)

For screen flows that are configured to run on API versions 57.0 and 58.0, on the Process Automation Settings page, select Enable Reactive Components for Screen Flows running API Version 57.0 and 58.0. Add components to your screen, and save and run your flows as usual.
The Enable Reactive Components for Screen Flows running API Version 57.0 and 58.0 setting expires in Winter ’25. Before that release, upgrade your flows to run on API version 59.0 or later to take advantage of reactive components.

